# How to handle SSL/TLS with kafka broker and schema registry all together?

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, confluent-schema-registry

i sadly havent found any infos on my topic when doing research. I am currently working on a kafka producer and the messages which are being produced to the broker should be encrypted via SSL. In the application there is also a call to the REST-API given by the schema registry. This call should also be encrypted (ig. SSL/HTTPS). How is that possible? Do I need only 1 key- and 1 truststore on the client side. What certificates do I need on the server side?

Thanks in advance.